# Different ways of calling map function in scala

Tags: scala, tuples

My function is

```
val f2 : (String, String) => Int = new Function2[String, String, Int] {
  def apply(s1 : String, s2 : String) = s1.length + s2.length
}
```

Why cannot I do this in Scala

```
val listOfFullNames = List(("Mark","Smith"), ("Jim","Duggan"), ("Eddie","Murphy"), ("Sylvester","Stallone"))

val output3 = listOfFullNames.map(f2)
```

The error message is interesting, it says expected: (String, String) => TypeInferredB, but actual (String, String) => Int

```
//But this works fine
val output3 = listOfFullNames.map(x => f2(x._1, x._2))
```

The reason I am doing this is purely because, this works

```
val f :String => Int = new Function[String, Int] {
  def apply(s : String) = s.length
}
```

this can be used like this

```
val listOfNames = List("Mark", "Jim", "Eddie", "Sylvester","Stallone")

val output = listOfNames.map(f)
```

Just want to know the difference between the following usages.

```
list.map(_.lowercase)

list.map(f)

listOfFullNames.map(x => f2(x._1, x._2))
```

Comment: I think you can just do `f2.tupled`.

Answer (score 5):

`listOfFullNames` is a `List` of tuples. A tuple is a single entity. `f2()` requires 2 individual `String` arguments so it won't accept a tuple instead.

If you look at the error message closely you'll notice the difference between `found: (String,String)` and `required: ((String,String))`.

As has been noted, `f2.tupled` will take a single tuple of type `(String,String)`.

```
val output3 = listOfFullNames.map(f2.tupled)  //this works
```

BTW, `f2()` can be expressed much more succinctly.

```
val f2 :(String, String) => Int = _.length + _.length
```